# 1M+ rows update in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, sql-update

We have 2 tables on production with 1M+ records each.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE `test_table2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `table1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `full_name` text,
  `full_name_esp` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

I need:

1. if in test_table2 full_name='' or full_name!=CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) - update column full_name with CONCAT(name, ' ', surname)
2. With full_name i need to update full_name_esp with spanish translation of full_name.

Tables are joined by a key test_table2.table1_id=test_table1.id

What is the best solution to this problem so as not to overload the production database?

My intended solution
1.

```
Create temp table 
test_table1_2 (`table1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, `full_name` text, `full_name_esp` text);
```

2. With Perl script

- get 1000 records from test_table1 test_table2 joined by test_table2.table1_id=test_table1.id
- do comparison.
- If i need to update full_name i make translation. and insert it into test_table1_2
- Then make update with:

```
update test_table1_2 t1, test_table2 t2 
set t2.full_name=t1.full_name, 
    t2.full_name_esp=t1.full_name_esp 
where t2.table1_id=t1.table1_id;
```

- `truncate test_table1_2`
- make step 2 again, until the end of records

Is this solution is good?

Comment: Did you test it? and did it work OK for you ?  Because "1M+ records" should not be a problem for a production server.

Comment: When your concern is a big (or too large/long) transaction, you can always add the `LIMIT` to the [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) statement, and repeat until no updates take place.

Comment: No i did'n test it. So you think it's good to insert all recored, tha sould be updated to test_table1_2, and the update them all in test_table2 with 1 transaction?

Comment: Can you give an example with UPDATE LIMIT in the context of the problem? Because LIMIT restrict the scope of the UPDATE whether or not the rows actually were changed.

Comment: You should see if the 1M+ records is a problem before examining alternatives. Why are you storing the same name in two places in your database? Can this be corrected?

Comment: Because afterward this fields test_table2.full_name,test_table2.full_name_esp can be changed by user, but fields in test_table1 - not